# Video JS Player - Work with http format and flash

Tags: flash, video.js, wowza

I am using a Video JS Player. I am forcing it to play with flash. But how can i force it to display a suitable error message like ' A link to install Flash', 'Flash not installed on your browser', in case client browser do not have flash installed.

Also, the videos are not getting played If I am using http link instead of rtmp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of "flash" doesn't use http for streaming it uses rtmp.

As for data be sure to onlys specify flash, then I think "flash not installed will appear":

data-setup='{"techOrder": ["flash"]}'

Maybe you need to enhance the messsage with a link.

```
var hasFlash = false;
try {
  var fo = new ActiveXObject('ShockwaveFlash.ShockwaveFlash');
  if (fo) {
    hasFlash = true;
  }
} catch (e) {
  if (navigator.mimeTypes
        && navigator.mimeTypes['application/x-shockwave-flash'] != undefined
        && navigator.mimeTypes['application/x-shockwave-flash'].enabledPlugin) {
    hasFlash = true;
  }
}
if(!hasFlash){
    d=document.getElementById("yourdivorspanthatisovertheplayer");
        d.style.visibility="visible";
        d.innerHTML="linktodownlaodflash":
}
```

Also look at https://github.com/brightcove/videojs-overlay/blob/master/example.html if you would like to do it smarter :)